# How many times substring occurs in string (error with printing typeerror)

Tags: python

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'

count = 0
for i in range(len(s)-2):
   count += s[i]=='b' and s[i+1]=='o' and s[i+2]=='b'

print(f'Number of times bob occurs is: {count}')
```

for example this should work right? when I type count into my commandline it gives me 2 which is the correct answer, however the print statement returns

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I've tried different versions of print such as

```
print('Number of times bob occurs is: ' + str(count))
```

and

```
print('Number of times bob occurs is: ' + int(count))
```

but they all give me errors, I know this is very basic but I am struggling with it and tried google, most of the stuff is more complex than it needs to be.

EDIT: Solved, I restarted my IDE and it started working, sorry for wasting everyones time.

Comment: have you tried `print('Number of times bob occurs is: %d' % count )`?

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: Simply don't lie about this being your code. Probably you really assigned an integer to `print`.

Comment: I just restarted my IDE and now it works?! Can someone explain? they all work now.

Comment: It seems like you defined a variable called print. Call you variable something else than print.

Comment: I see you have found MIT course...Good ! :)

Comment: yep been at it, oh god the next question is way harder.

Answer (score -1):

This would be the **better** generic solution:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'

find_str = "bob"

_i = 0
_count = 0
while _i <= len(s):
    if s[_i:_i+len(find_str)] == find_str:
            _count += 1
    _i += 1

print("Number of times {} occurs is: {}".format(find_str, _count))
```

It works fine, **but not the correct way**. What if you have a sting of bigger length ??

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'

count = 0
for i in range(len(s)-2):
    count += s[i]=='b' and s[i+1]=='o' and s[i+2]=='b'

print('Number of times bob occurs is: {}'.format(count))
# Number of times bob occurs is: 2
```

Comment: It wasn't working for me, I restarted my IDE and now it does.

Comment: 's = 'azcbobobegghakl'

count = 0
for i in range(len(s)-2):
   count += s[i:i+3]=='bob'

print(f'Number of times bob occurs is: {count}')'

Would this be more correct?

Comment: can I just ask, is this the "correct" way of doing this? I am struggling to naturally write code, I stole this from like 10 different sources and jerryrigged it. Is this the correct way?

Comment: @FitnessRegiment updated the above solution, your method is not correct.

Comment: This "answer" has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, OP might be assigning the print to a integer which is not mentioned in the question, but the code itself won't work for other strings.

Comment: as I said it could have happened earlier, I have no idea to be honest but restarting the IDE worked.